# CSS file is not linking to HTML and not formatting as per CSS code

Tags: html, css

I have created a header with logo, menu and social icons all in one menu bar.[image]

Now my problem is I am unable to move the text as I desired. CSS coding is not at all reflecting in the final result.

my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Social Menu </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/social/social.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/social/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>

<div class="header-section">
<div class="logo">
<h3> New Horizons </h3>
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="social">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<div class="container">
<div class="content-area">
<p> Our business model </p>
</div>
<div class="image">
<img src>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<p> &copy, 2021 all rights reserved </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My css code

```
html,body {
margin:0;

}

/*setting full width header */

.header-section {
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:10%;
margin:0;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
border-bottom:3px solid black;
background-color:#444442;
box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
}

/* setting logo */

.logo {
width:33%;
text-align:left;
flex:1;
}

/* setting navigation */

nav {
width:33%;
text-align:center;
flex:1;
}   

/* setting social menu */
.social {
width:33%;
text-align:right;
flex:1

}

/*logo style */

.logo h3 {
font-family:Architects daughter, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:150%;
margin-left:15px;
color:yellow;
float:left;
flex:1;
}

/*menu style */

ul {
display:flex;
margin-left:35px;
flex:1;
}


ul li {
list-style-type:none;
float:right;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;

}

ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#42cefc;
font-family:Architechts daughter, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:100%;
float:left;
display:inline;
flex:1;
padding-top:8px 25px 8px 25px;
margin:15px;
box-sizing:border-box;
]

/*social media icons */

.social ul {
display:flex;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:8px;
flex:1;
}

.social ul li {
list-style-type:none;
float:right;
vertical-align:right;
display:inline;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing:border-box;

}

.social ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:150%;
float:right;
display:inline;
flex:1;
padding-top:5px;
padding-right:60px;
margin-left:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
]

/* main content area */

.container {
width:100%;
margin-right:15px;
}


.content-area {
width:50%;
border-top:3px solid black;
margin-right:10px;
}



footer {

text-align: center;
font-size: 85%;
font-color: #f2cede;
padding-bottom: 20px;

}
```

Container section and footer section are not formatted as given in CSS. Moreover I am unable to create (divs) after the header section in HTML.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's in your css. On two lines you have closed the styles with a square bracket `]` instead of curly `}`. Moreover, `font-color` is not a css property. Simply use `color`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*setting full width header */

.header-section {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #444442;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}


/* setting logo */

.logo {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
}


/* setting navigation */

nav {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}


/* setting social menu */

.social {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1
}


/*logo style */

.logo h3 {
  font-family: Architects daughter, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: yellow;
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
}


/*menu style */

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 35px;
  flex: 1;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #42cefc;
  font-family: Architechts daughter, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*social media icons */

.social ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  flex: 1;
}

.social ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: right;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 150%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* main content area */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.content-area {
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 85%;
  color: #f2cede;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

place your html file and CSS file in the same folder and call the CSS file in link href by its relative path

like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="social.css" type="text/css">
```

it will work, it will automatically take the whole url with the endpoint placing as social.css